# How to call new css file in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I am developing an online store in magento.I am editing the default theme of magento according to my new theme.
I wanted to know how can I call new css and js file to my default theme.
I tried making a blocktype in layout/page.xml like:-

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/bootstrap.css</stylesheet></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
```

css/widgets.css
  css/print.cssmedia="print"

i want to add bootstrap.css file to my theme but its not included in the meta tag
Please help me

Comment: `....but its not included in the meta tag`? why in meta tag?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addCss">
        <style>css/filename.css</style>
    </action>
</reference>
```